# TikZ: Symmetric matrix without upper diagonal elements

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a symmetric matrix in TikZ and don't want to show the upper diagonal elements.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(U.center)]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=[ ,right delimiter={]},  nodes={outer sep=1pt}] (U) { 
 0  &   \textcolor{white}{9} & \textcolor{white}{3} & \textcolor{white}{6} & \textcolor{white}{11}   \\[0.1cm]
 9  &   0 & \textcolor{white}{11} & \textcolor{white}{11} & \textcolor{white}{11}   \\[0.1cm]
 3  &   7 & 0 & \textcolor{white}{11} &  \textcolor{white}{11}   \\[0.1cm]
 6  &   5 & 9 & 0 &   \textcolor{white}{11}   \\[0.1cm]
11 & 10 & 2 & 8 &   0   \\[0.1cm]
 };

\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{
 \node[black,  left = 3 mm of U-\x-1] (U-\x-6) {$\x$};
 };

\foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
 \node[black, above= 1 mm of U-1-\y] (U-6-\y)  {$\y$};
 };

\draw[red] ([shift={(4pt, 2pt)}]U-1-1.north west) -- ([shift={(5pt,2pt)}]U-5-5.south east);
\draw[red] ([shift={(-5pt, -2pt)}]U-1-1.north west) -- ([shift={(-4pt,-2pt)}]U-5-5.south east);

\draw[red] ([shift={(5pt, 2pt)}]U-1-1.north west) -- ([shift={(-5pt,-2pt)}]U-1-1.north west);
\draw[red] ([shift={(5pt, 2pt)}]U-5-5.south east) -- ([shift={(-5pt,-2pt)}]U-5-5.south east);

\node [draw, circle, red] at (U-5-3) {};

\node[black,  left = 6 mm of U] {$\mathbf{D}=\left\{ d_{ij}\right\}=$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder how to get the blank upper diagonal elements without using the white text color of the elements. Thanks

Comment: Do not write anything there or use at least an empty group: `{}`. Furthermore check out the options `nodes in empty cell` and `execute at empty cell` (or similar). You can also use `text=white` as an option to those nodes or `text opacity=0` (which works on every background). A TeX solution would be to use `\phantom{<number>}` which also hides the number from the PDF. The others are all selectable and copyable. (And please reduce your example to an MWE. Do we need the right lines and the math stuff as well as the delimiters?

Comment: If you just use the proper number of cell delimiters (`&`) without any cell content, it should work. Of course if you read the matrix from an external source, you need to think about something else... but with your MWE, this should be ok.

Comment: Besides the right solutions Qrrbrbirbel and Count Zero provided, there's one more as you already loaded the `fit` library: fit the nodes with a white filling with something like `\node[fit=(U-1-4),fill=white,inner sep=0pt]{};` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Using `{}` works but it also changes the position of the column name.

Comment: @CountZero Concerning cells at the end of the row it is also permissible to leave the `&` and simply start a next line with ``\\``.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You can use `font=\strut` or directly `{\strut}` or other tricks with `minimum height` and `minimum width` and such to ensure a node that can be used for the column labels. You can also place the nodes in relation to the matrix (yes, that's a node too): `\node at (U.north -| U-5-1) {1};` and so on. This would make it independent of the height of the nodes in the matrix. If you use the last row, you don't even need nodes in the other rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TikZ inside an equation and since your diagonal is full you don't need any nodes inside the upper diagonal entries. Often the delimiters come out too wide so a little nudge towards inside looks better (opinion!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{D}=\{ d_{ij} \}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(U.center),
                    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1mm},
                    every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-1mm}]

\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
         inner sep=0pt,
         left delimiter={[}, 
         right delimiter={]},
         nodes={inner sep=0,minimum size=6mm,anchor=center}
        ] (U) { 
 0&  &  &  &  \\
 9& 0&  &  &  \\
 3& 7& 0&  &  \\
 6& 5& 9& 0&  \\
11&10& 2& 8& 0\\
};
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{\\
\node[left]  at (U-\x-\x.west -| U.west) {$\x$};
\node[above] at (U-\x-\x.north|- U.north) {$\x$};
}
\draw[red] (U-1-1.north) -- (U-1-1.west) -- (U-5-5.south) -- (U-5-5.east) -- cycle;
\node [draw, circle, red] at (U-5-3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @percusse for your answer. It seems like that this code does not work in `\documentclass{standalone}`.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Yes because standalone uses a different boxing then the normal documents. You can revert back to your original in case you need external image.

Comment: Is this possible to get work this code in `\documentclass{standalone}`? Because  `\documentclass{standalone}` produces well cropped picture. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to use this inside a document? Then remove the formula part and use the matrix via `\includegraphics`.